# Memory leak in dwm (Desktop Window Manager) using Animations in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, memory-leaks, dwm

I have written a music Player for UWP that uses some animations while playing music like an rotating cover.

[image]

I noticed that the Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe) consumes around an MB memory each second. The animation shown above consumes around 300-400kb each second. Closing the App will not release the memory.

Pausing the Animation will stop the leek. Resume it and it start leaking again.

The Animated element is defined like this (The complete file is on [github](https://github.com/LokiMidgard/Bes-Music/blob/master/MusicPlayer/Controls/NowPlayingDisk.xaml)):

```xml
<Ellipse
    x:Name="CoverDisc"
    Margin="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ProgressThikness, Converter={StaticResource thiknessConver}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource thiknessParameter}}"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    Stroke="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=BorderBrush}"
    StrokeThickness="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ProgressThikness}">
    <Ellipse.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard">
            <DoubleAnimation
                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                To="360"
                Duration="0:0:20" />
            <!--  Duration="0:0:1.8" this is record spped  -->
        </Storyboard>
    </Ellipse.Resources>
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="transform" />
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Cover, ElementName=root, TargetNullValue={StaticResource FallbackCover}}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

The Animation is controled via code behind:

```cs
private static void IsPlayingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var me = d as NowPlayingDisk;
    var elipse = me.CoverDisc;
    if (elipse is null)
        return;
    var storyboard = elipse.Resources["Storyboard"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard;
    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        if (storyboard.GetCurrentState() == Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ClockState.Stopped)
            storyboard.Begin();
        else
            storyboard.Resume();
    }
    else
        storyboard.Pause();
}
```

What can I do besides not using any animations to keep the memory footprint down? I've noticed that dwm consumed over 7Gb in the past making working with the machine almost impossible.

I use this app for some time now and I'm not sure if that problem was always there. It did run in the past for several hours and at least I didn't noticed anything that consumed so much memory.

I'm running on a Surface Pro 6 with a current Windows version:

```
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 20H2
Installiert am  ‎16.‎10.‎2020
Betriebssystembuild 19042.964
Leistung    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0

Prozessor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz   2.11 GHz
Installierter RAM   16,0 GB
Systemtyp   64-Bit-Betriebssystem, x64-basierter Prozessor
```

---

**EDIT**

I was able to test it on another machine which runs an older version of Windows.
On that machine was no problem at all with memory consumption.

```
Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 1908
Betriebssystembuild 17763.1879
```

Comment: Are you using an Intel graphics driver that leaks memory? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058381/graphics/graphics-for-8th-generation-intel-processors.html

Comment: @PatrikLundquist Yes I did, I just updated, and now I'm testing if I still can reproduce the memory leak

Comment: @PatrikLundquist It seems to Wokr :) Memory of dwm did not increase over an houre

Answer (score 0):

If the music is playing and you close the app, since the storyboard object of memory is used, which might cause the storyboard object can't be released. Therefore, I suggest you could release the memory object in the Suspending event that attached to the App class. As follows:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += App_Suspending;
}
private void App_Suspending(Object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    storyboard.Pause();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. Any idea while the animation constantly consumes memory it does not release?

Comment: I have tested your code snippet, it works well on my PC. When I play the animation, it can’t generate a memory leak. If you have more devices, you could test it on PC with different version operation system to check whether it also happens, if this issue doesn’t happen, it might be related to the specified PC.

Comment: @Arya-ding-msft I have testet it on another PC with different OS and Processor. There I didn't had the same issue. (see edit). I need to test it on more PCs.. to see if it is more often a problem or just my current setup.

Comment: My PC operation system is also Windows10 20H2, but I haven’t this situation. Generally this memory leak doesn’t happen, maybe this issue is related your PC.